# Horizontal scroll of table/collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have an array with unknown amount of items in it and I need to scroll them horizontaly with one item per page. Basicly, I want smt like [this](https://github.com/BenEmdon/CenteredCollectionView/blob/master/GitHub/demo.gif) (for some reaons this project doesn't work for me).

So, the obvious solution would be to create `CollectionView` inside `TableViewCell`, but the questions are:

First, how can I leaf them over like in the example above? `CollectionViewCells` move smoothly like a `scrollView`, but I need to "swap" between them. 
Second, how to display one cell per page? And should I even pick `CollectionView` approach? Because I can not find anything like this in the internet.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at `UIPageViewController`? Sounds more suitable to your task... Here is a simple example: https://github.com/DonMag/SWEmbeddedPageView

Comment: Yes, but I have a big amount of items in my array: from 5 to few hundred, and the numbers are always different. So, I didn't figure out how to do this with this approach

Comment: You can load each "page" as it is requested, just like you load each cell in a collection view as it is requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you can make each collection view cell the same size as the whole application screen.
Then set these attributes to your UICollectionView:

```
...
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpasing = 0
    let yourCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    yourCollectionView.pagingEnabled = true
.....
```

The example is in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kecV6xPTTr8&index=1&t=1s&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JHfozquTVhV4HRy-1A_aXlv

Comment: It works, but is it possible not to fill the entire view with CollectionViewCell, but place Cell just in the center of the CollectionView? If you take a look at [this](https://github.com/BenEmdon/CenteredCollectionView/blob/master/GitHub/demo.gif) link, there is a rectangle in the middle of the screen. I don't know how to do this with your approach...

Comment: Yes, It's possible I think. Try to play with different sizes of your cells and with insets. Also, with this one layout.minimumLineSpasing